# Google Forms: How can I edit the original responses to match new list options

Tags: google-forms

I am using a google form. I have a question called "Weight Class" which was originally a text input. After a few submissions, I decided that I wanted to see them summarized in the Summary of Responses (like google does with dropdown list inputs), rather than just listed individually (like google does with text inputs), so I changed the "Weight Class" form input to a dropdown list input. Some of the responses I received before changing the input don't match the new list options. For example the new list option was `Mens 77kg`, but some of the original text input responses were `77kg`,`Men's 77kg`, `Mens 77`, etc. Since these responses aren't in the list of options, they don't get counted in the summary of responses.

Is there a way to edit the original responses to match the new list options? Editing the responses spreadsheet does not update the original responses, which are used for the summary.

Original Responses: `77kg, 85kg, 105kg`
List Options: `Mens 77kg, Mens 85kg, Mens 105kg`

How can I edit the original responses, so that they match the format of the new list options?

**Responses:**

```
+---------+--------------+
| Name    | Weight Class |
+---------+--------------+
| Person1 | 77kg         | *original row
+---------+--------------+
| Person2 | 85kg         | *original row
+---------+--------------+
| Person3 | 105kg        | *original row
+---------+--------------+
| Person4 | Mens 85kg    | *new row
+---------+--------------+
```

**SUMMARY OF RESPONSES:**

```
+---------+
|  Names  |
+---------+
| Person1 |
+---------+
| Person2 |
+---------+
| Person3 |
+---------+
| Person4 |
+---------+    
+--------------+-------+------+
| Weight Class | Count |   %  |
+--------------+-------+------+
|   Mens 77kg  |   0   |  0%  |
+--------------+-------+------+
|   Mens 85kg  |   1   | 100% |
+--------------+-------+------+
|   Mens 105kg |   0   |  0%  |
+--------------+-------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research it appears that you can't edit the original responses by design, so it was not possible to fix the current form and responses in the way that I wanted.

If someone knows of a way to edit the original responses, please let me know.

**WORKAROUND**

My workaround solution was to create a new copy of the form and enter all of the corrected original data. I created a copy of the form, and resubmitted all of the original answers with the corrected weight class.I then replaced all links to the old form with links to the new form. The summary of responses is now correct.

**EDITED RESPONSES**

```
+---------+--------------+
| Name    | Weight Class |
+---------+--------------+
| Person1 | Mens 77kg    | *original row
+---------+--------------+
| Person2 | Mens 85kg    | *original row
+---------+--------------+
| Person3 | Mens 105kg   | *original row
+---------+--------------+
| Person4 | Mens 85kg    | *new row
+---------+--------------+
```

**CORRECTED SUMMARY**

```
+---------+
|  Names  |
+---------+
| Person1 |
+---------+
| Person2 |
+---------+
| Person3 |
+---------+
| Person4 |
+---------+    
+--------------+-------+------+
| Weight Class | Count |   %  |
+--------------+-------+------+
|   Mens 77kg  |   1   |  25% |
+--------------+-------+------+
|   Mens 85kg  |   2   |  50% |
+--------------+-------+------+
|   Mens 105kg |   1   |  25% |
+--------------+-------+------+
```